# Create javascript Date() object to Amrica/New_York timezone

Tags: javascript, date

The code:

```
console.log(start)
```

reads, **Thu Mar 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**

I want it a new object start_NY which will read **Thu Mar 01 2018 00:00:00** w.r.t. `America/New_York` timezone. Something like **Thu Mar 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500**.

I used a script:

```
start_ny = new Date('Thu Mar 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT-0500');
```

But that reads, **Thu Mar 01 2018 10:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**, which is actually converting the date into Indian Standard Time, instead of giving me a time from New_York timezone.

The format should be same as that of the existing one. How can I do that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialize javascript date to a particular timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-javascript-date-to-a-particular-timezone)

Comment: check [moment library](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)
you can define it as the following:
`var newYork    = moment.tz("2014-06-01 12:00", "America/New_York");`
`newYork.format();`

Comment: @karim it returns 2018-03-01T00:00:00Z, which is totally different from the format I want. Check the question minutely.

Comment: Don't use the built-in parser, [it's notoriously unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results). A library will help greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this following code and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) resources

```
new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' })

// Date Format

new Date().toDateString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' });
```

Comment: This returns `3/11/2018, 11:33:58 AM` which is not exactly the format I want.

Comment: @Saswat—if you want to format a date, then see [*Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)